# Group by Week with starting week beginning at first of month with groupdate gem Ruby on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I'm using `groupdate` **gem** by Ankane for context. When I attempt to `group_by_week` for a range of dates, in certain cases, it starts the week with dates included for the previous month. I know that the week starts differently for certain months. But, I would like to `group_by_week` and force the results to stay within the range of dates for the month. How can I get the `group_by_week` method to stay within the constraints of the given month? Example: `return group_by_week`(range: July 1st - July 31st).sum(:powerups)

code example that returns dates from previous month in group_by_week results.

**date_finder.rb**

```
target_date = Date.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, 1)

Post.group_by_week(:created_at, range: target_date.beginning_of_month..target_date.end_of_month).sum(:view_count)
```

Results Example: returns 6/28/2020 - 7/26/2020
Expected Results: 7/01/2020 - 7/31/2020

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to select the records you want, and only then group by week...

```
target_date = Date.today.beginning_of_month
target_range = target_date..target_date.end_of_month

Post.where(created_at: target_range).group_by_week(:created_at, range: target_range).sum(:view_count)
```

Comment: I'll test it tomorrow and give my feedback.

Comment: I'm still receiving records from the end of the month before. For instance, when I use your method with July...I get Week 1 as June 28 2020 to July 7, 2020. Week 2 as July 5, 2020 to 7/12/2020. and so forth. Its not returning July only dates, but calculating the sum as weeks.

Comment: If possible, can you test whether or not you're getting the same results as me?

Comment: I'll give it a try, get back to you over the next 24 hours.